# Show convergence of $\int_1^\infty{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can I show that $I=\int_1^\infty{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}}$ converges. I've had no success with finding any bounding function.

I also tried tried trig-substitution so $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}}=\int_0^{\pi/2}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}}$. But this did not help me.

Comment: Looking for a way to show it without wolframalpha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cases like these, it may be useful to look at the asymptotic behaviour. You say you couldn't find a bounding function, but if it were $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x}}$ I'm quite certain you could.

The fact is that you almost immediately *want* to compare with some kind of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}}$. So what you can do is show that this is asymptotically the same as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x}}$, in the sense that $\frac{1/\sqrt{x^3+x}}{1/\sqrt{x^3}} \to 1$ as $x \to +\infty$. With this fact at hand, you now have that for $x$ greater than a certain $K$, it is true that $\frac{1/\sqrt{x^3+x}}{1/\sqrt{x^3}} < 2$, say. Therefore, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+x}}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^3}}$ for those $x>K$, which gives you enough to conclude the exercise. This strategy also is easily generalizable for other cases. (Note that it isn't necessary for the limit to actually be $1$. It suffices for it to exist as a real number.)

Answer (score 5):

Note that for $x>1$, we have that $2<x(x+1)$ and $(x-1)^2<x(x+1)$ therefore
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}=\frac{1}{((x-1)x(x+1))^{1/2}}<\frac{1}{(2(x-1))^{1/2}}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}=\frac{1}{((x-1)x(x+1))^{1/2}}<\frac{1}{((x-1)^3)^{1/2}}.$$
Can you take if from here?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a bounding function if you've found an  *equivalent function*  near $1$ and  near $\infty$ (in general they're not the same) for which the integral functions $\int_1^a$ and $\int_a^\infty$ converge.

- Near $\infty$, $x^3-x\sim x^3$, so $\;\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^3-x}}\sim_\infty \dfrac1{x^{3/2}}$, and the integral to $\infty$ of this function converges.
- Near $1$, set $x=t-1$. The integral becomes
  $$\int_1^a\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}=\int_0^{a+1}\!\!\!\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{2t-3t^2+t^3}}$$
  and near $t=0$, we have $\;\dfrac{\mathrm 1}{\sqrt{2t-3t^2+t^3}}\sim\dfrac{\mathrm 1}{\sqrt{2t}}$, which has a convergent integral.

Comment: Is there a proof of such equivalency?

Comment: It is based on the elementary result that a polynomial is equivalent near $0$  to its lower degree term and near $\infty$ to its leading term. The rest is just  checking equivalence remains when you take square roots (equivalence  is compatible with multiplication and division).

Comment: Unsure still follow. How to show a polynomial is equivalent near 0 to its lowest-degree term with respect to integration?

Comment: This equivalence is independent of integration: it is a notion of asymptotic analysis. It just means, roughly speaking, that the quotient tends to $1$. And it is  a basic result that the integrals of two equivalent functions both converge or both diverge. Same result for series.

Comment: @Quanto If you're looking for more details than Berand's last comment, I recommend posting your latter question as a separate question here---at least provided it wouldn't be a duplicate---since it's a worthwhile question in its own right, and a detailed answer would be too involved for comments.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. Always wonder if there is rigorous proof re. applying to integral convergence.

Comment: It's a theorem in asymptotic analysis and,  as far as I remember, it was proved rigourously when I was a student.

Answer (score 3):

$I_1=\int_1^\infty{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2}}}$ converges. The integrand lies above the integrad of $I_2=\int_1^\infty{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}}$ for all $x>1$.

So the area under the first on is greater than the area under the second one. So your integral must be less than the first one. Since area under the curve is equal to the integral.

$I_1$ can easily be computed and is $2arctan{(x-1)}^{0.5}$ which is equal to $pi$ which means that your integral is less than $pi$ but greater $0$.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the simplest way is just to enforce the substitution $x\mapsto x+1$ and then break the integral into simpler pieces:
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+3x^2+2x}} \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x}}+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3}} = \sqrt{2}+2.$$
You may also notice that the second term is an elliptic integral:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(x^2+3x+2)}}\stackrel{x\mapsto x^2}{=}2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+2}}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}} $$
and the last term equals $\frac{\pi}{\text{AGM}(a,b)} $ where $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$, so
$$\boxed{2.60258\ldots= \frac{2\pi}{1+\sqrt{2}}\leq\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x}}\leq \frac{\pi}{2^{1/4}}=2.64175\ldots.}$$
By the relations between $K$ (the complete elliptic integral of the first kind) and the $\text{AGM}$ the exact value of the integral is $\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}=2.62205755429211981\ldots.$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{1 \over \root{x^{3} - x}} & \sim
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\ds{{1 \over \root{2}}\,\pars{x - 1}^{-1/2}} &
\mbox{as}\ds{\ x \to 1^{+}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{x^{-3/2}} & \mbox{as}\ds{\ x \to \infty}
\end{array}\right.
\\[5mm]
&\mbox{That's}\ \underline{enough}\ \mbox{to ensure the}\
\underline{convergence}\ \mbox{!!!.}
\end{align}